# Why are the bodies of my dead dwellers disappearing in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was wondering why some of my dead dwellers have disappeared?

It wasn't all of them, and it wasn't necessarily the ones that had been dead the longest.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade :) I've suggested an edit to your question, that should make it easier to read in the main view, and attract more response. Hope this helps, and be sure to read the FAQs and tour to get the best out of your time here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I know how dwellers will disappear is a death time over 24 hours.

It may be that you haven't seen it, or haven't mentioned with dweller was dead for the longest time. But normally they just stay for 24 hours in your vault. After this time is used up and you haven't reanimated them, they disappear (with all their stuff).

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that your dead dwellers are 'piling up'. I noticed that every time i opened the game my dead bodies would be piling up, i was thinking they disappeared until i realised they just all pile up in the same spot, very very slowly...

Answer (score 0):

I have not verified this, but I noticed that if I filled the room with new dwellers where corpse was previously working in, the corpse may disappear after i relog back in next time. Perhaps the slot where the corpse was was overwritten by the new dweller.